# TypeError while uploading image using REST api in OpenShift V3

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, openshift, openshift-nextgen

I have a **[Django App](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B0DlE-Qi4Fu6cEVXUVpxMFZYeFk)** that accept images through REST-api. I tested the api using **[POSTMAN](https://www.getpostman.com/)** locally, it's working perfect with image uploads. Later I deployed it on **OpenShift V3** and when I tried the same for uploading process using POSTMAN , it's saying

[image]

**Server Traceback**

```
Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://django-psql-persistent-sampledjangoex.44fs.preview.openshiftapps.com/myapp/sample/

Django Version: 1.9
Python Version: 3.5.1
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'debug_toolbar',
 'welcome',
 'rest_framework')
Installed Middleware:
('debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware')



Traceback:

File "/opt/app-root/src/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  174.                     response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/opt/app-root/src/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  172.                     response = response.render()

File "/opt/app-root/src/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/response.py" in render
  160.             self.content = self.rendered_content

File "/opt/app-root/src/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/rest_framework/response.py" in rendered_content
  71.         ret = renderer.render(self.data, media_type, context)

File "/opt/app-root/src/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/rest_framework/renderers.py" in render
  104.             separators=separators

File "/opt/rh/rh-python35/root/usr/lib64/python3.5/json/__init__.py" in dumps
  237.         **kw).encode(obj)

File "/opt/rh/rh-python35/root/usr/lib64/python3.5/json/encoder.py" in encode
  199.         chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)

File "/opt/rh/rh-python35/root/usr/lib64/python3.5/json/encoder.py" in iterencode
  257.         return _iterencode(o, 0)

File "/opt/app-root/src/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/rest_framework/utils/encoders.py" in default
  64.         return super(JSONEncoder, self).default(obj)

File "/opt/rh/rh-python35/root/usr/lib64/python3.5/json/encoder.py" in default
  180.         raise TypeError(repr(o) + " is not JSON serializable")

Exception Type: TypeError at /myapp/sample/
Exception Value: b'\xff\xd8\xff\xe0\x00\x10JFIF\x00\x01\x01\x00\x00\x01\x00\x01\x00\x00\xff\xdb\x00C\x00\x06\x04\x05\x06\x05\x04\x06\x06\x05\x06\x07\x07\x06\x08\n' is not JSON serializable
```

Here is the [source Code of the Program](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B0DlE-Qi4Fu6cEVXUVpxMFZYeFk)

Note: I can do uploading process through **DRF-Browsable api**

Comment: Screenshot is useless. Please provide server traceback.

Comment: can you provide your code ?

Comment: @Raz
I updated the question with Traceback, Please check it out

Comment: @C̲̅R̲̅O̲̅Z̲̅E̲̅T̲̅
you can find the source code [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0DlE-Qi4Fu6cEVXUVpxMFZYeFk/view)

Comment: Looks like you have exception during the handling of another exception. Try debug this line: `response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)` in /opt/app-root/src/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py. Get value of `e`. This is original exception. Django tried to render it and failed.

Comment: @Raz
I have no problem/error when I run the project locally. Then how can I debug ?

Comment: I never used OpenShift. Do you have ssh access to the server? If you have you can just call print next to the line 174 in django/core/handlers/base.py. Additionally try to make request from python with requests library. Not with  the postman. I think you have issue in your request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all I would say thanks to @[Raz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/575365/raz). Actually the tool POSTMAN caused the issue. I tested the OpenShift-v3 api using Python's Request library. It's worked :)

Code I used;

```
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth

url = 'http://django-psql-persistent-sampledjangoex.44fs.preview.openshiftapps.com/myapp/sample/'
filess = {'image': open('sampleImage.png', 'rb')}
r = requests.post(url,data={'name': 'value1', 'number': 12573474},auth=HTTPBasicAuth('admin', 'admin'),files=filess)
```